# Is there a way to use compare a list with a dictionary key, then rearrange that list element to be in the value position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary that defines the mapping I want. for example, I want list item 2 to be swapped to the list item 5 position

```
# FOR ENCRYPTION - Create dictionary mapping inputs to outputs of pbox of form {input:output}
pboxEncrypt = {1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 9, 4: 13, 5: 2, 6: 6, 7: 10, 8: 14, 9: 3, 10: 7, 11: 11, 12: 15, 13: 4, 15: 12, 16: 16}
```

I have a divded_list containing 16 individual binary string values, namely:

```
Divided List : ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I would like to build a function where I pass in the divided_list and pbx, loop to see if the list index matches the dictionary key, if list index=key, store this list element in a temporary list under the index defined by the dictionary value. The function returns the temporary array of rearranged values.

(assuming an index starting position of 1) an example output of this function would be:

list item at index position #3 ['1'] should be stored in the temporary list at index position #9

```
divided_list = [x , x , 1 , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x ]
```

After dictionary mapping swap

```
temp_list =    [x , x , x , x , x , x , x , x , 1 , x , x , x , x , x , x , x ]
```

Now for my approach to solving this issue:

```
def mapPBOX(div_list, pbx):
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(1,16):
        key_list = pbx.keys()           #make list of dict keys
        val_list = pbx.values()         #make list of dict values
        for match in key_list:
            if div_list[i] == key_list[match]:
                temp_list[val_list[match]] = div_list[i]    #map
    return temp_list
```

Which returns an error of:

```
    if div_list[i] == key_list[match]:
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

If `temp_list[val_list[match]] = div_list[i]` is not subscriptable, how should I retrieve the numerical value in the dictionary, and then perform a swap on the div_list item location?

I am familiar with using arrays in other languages like C, but python and dictionaries are both new to me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, a simple list comprehension would work.
Note that indexing starts with 0 in python, so you need to correct here.
Also you have missing mappings in your dictionary. I left those indexes unchanged.

```
pboxEncrypt = {1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 9, 4: 13, 5: 2, 6: 6, 7: 10, 8: 14, 9: 3, 10: 7, 11: 11, 12: 15, 13: 4, 15: 12, 16: 16}
divded_list = ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']

out = [divded_list[pboxEncrypt.get(i+1, i+1)-1] 
       for i in range (len(divded_list))]
```

Output:

```
['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0']
```